# Сохранение игрового рекорда

Tags: unity3d

Я нубас нубовский. Объясните где я туплю в скрипте.
Делаю игру на Юнити по видео-туториалу. Это простая гиперказуальная гиперказуалка. В центре экрана по кругу движется шарик. При тапе на экран (на весь экран скрытая большая кнопка) шарик меняет направление по часовой или против часовой.
Слева направо летят объекты "враги" и "бонусы". От врагов надо уворачиваться бонусы собирать. Собрал бонус плюс одно очко, ударился о врага минус одно очко.
Наверху экрана два текстовых поля: текущие очки и игровой рекорд.
Вот с этим рекордом и проблемы. В туториале его небыло. Я его решил сам добавить. Погуглил, сделал все как для текущих очков и написал

```
if (ochki >= record) record = ochki;
RecordText.text = record.ToString();
```

Всё работает, рекорд отображается и изменяется.
Но только до конца игры. При выключении и повторном включении игры рекорд блин обнуляется. В общем я решил сделать сохранение, чтобы рекорд сохранялся при следующем запуске игры и последующих запусках и продолжал подсчитываться, как оно вроде бы и должно быть.
Опять погуглил но на этот раз неудачно или я сам туплю.
В общем написал в методе Update

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("My");
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("My", record);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Visual Studio говорит что все ништяк, ошибок нет, но ни хрена не сохраняется игра (игровой рекорд то есть)
Пробовал запихнуть всё это PlayerPrefs в метод OnApplicationQuit но результат тот же.

Вроде бы всё что надо есть, "My" это ключ, record интовая переменная значение которой я пытаюсь сохранить до следующего запуска игры.

Вот скрипт полностью

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MSHARIKA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ochki;
    public int record;
    [SerializeField] Text OchkiText;
    [SerializeField] Text RecordText;    
    
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Etot)
    {
        if (Etot.gameObject.tag == "tag2")
        {
            Destroy(Etot.gameObject);
            ochki++;
        }

        if (Etot.gameObject.tag == "tag1")
        {
            Destroy(Etot.gameObject);
            ochki+=-1;
        }

    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (ochki >= record) record = ochki;
        RecordText.text = record.ToString();
        OchkiText.text = ochki.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.GetInt("My");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("My", record);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

}
```

Скрипт висит на самом шарике, очки прибавляются и убавляются при столкновении с объектами в зависимости от tag1 и tag2. При столкновении с шариком объекты также исчезают.

В общем работает всё кроме сохранения рекорда после выключения игры.

Объясните пожалуйста где я туплю?

Если можно напишите и пару-тройку строчек кода как мне в моем скрипте это сохранение игрового рекорда сделать.

Буду благодарен за все ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сохранения данных игры нужно реализовать сохранение данных в файловой системе и их считывание. То есть нужно при закрытии игры (в данном случае при выполнении условия)записать переменную, которую нужно сохранить в файл, а при загрузке игры считать из файла в переменную. В данном случае лучше всего использовать встроенный класс PlayerPrefs.

```
void Start()
    {
           record = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("My");
    }

void Update()
{
    if (ochki > record)
    {
        record = ochki;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("My", record);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: OwlCherubael Спасибо! Написал по Вашему совету, всё работает, что интересно обновленное приложение подхватило прошлый рекорд который получается сохранялся но не отображался после нового запуска, потом почистил кеш и данные через диспетчер приложений и всё заработало "с нуля" и отображается и сохраняется. Тут ещё в "ответе на ответ" нет функций редактирования, строки не переносятся, код не выделяется, я ещё в ответе на свой же вопрос дополнительно написал Вам, там редактирование нормальное.

Comment: @AnValery, ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию, помимо того, чтобы сохранять рекорд при его изменении, надо ещё его считать при запуске, сохранить в соответствующую переменную и вывести в поле.

Comment: Qwertiy Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

OwlCherubael Спасибо ещё раз, что-то здесь ответ на ответ как-то заморочено устроен по оформлению, строки не переносятся и т.д. (или я опять туплю)) так что я решил ещё раз написать в ответе на свой же вопрос, здесь вроде по оформлению всё нормально, строки переносятся, код выделяется и т.д.
Вот так написал по Вашему совету

```
    public void Start()
    {
        record = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("My");
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        if (ochki >= record) record = ochki;
        RecordText.text = record.ToString();
        OchkiText.text = ochki.ToString();
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("My", record);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();            

    }
```